# How do I get my duplicants to finish a dirty job before showering

Tags: oxygen-not-included

If I assign a spill to be mopped I often find that a duplicant turns up, spends 5 seconds mopping and then goes for a shower, even though the job isn't done. After the shower they come back and spend another 5 seconds mopping before returning for another shower. A mopping job of 10 tiles can result in the duplicant taking 5 or 6 showers.

How do I get my duplicants to finish the whole mopping job and then just take one shower after the job is done?

Comment: Perhaps you could set the priority of the mop higher than the shower?

Comment: The mobs are insane. Assign them to med beds.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by setting up a different schedule with a section of "work" before "bathtime" for particular duplicants that have a high tidying priority, see the following examples:
[image: Priority Editor]
[image: Schedule Editor]

As you can see, Travaldo is a duplicant that has the highest tidying priority but has "work" before "bathtime". Couple this with the priority system and Travaldo will always mop liquids before anything else.
Make sure they have enough time to clean up messes before bathtime, otherwise the same issue you described will sprung.